# How react-router send request to server middleware from client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to understand this code : How does `react-router` work with an isomorphic app, (server and client side routing). How react-router on client side can send request to middleware on the server ?

Link to [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router)

Answer (score 0):

> How react-router on client side can send request to middleware

**It doesn't send requests to server.**

React router is responsible (From docs):

> React Router keeps your UI in sync with the URL

Please check this https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/Introduction.md and first section `Without React Router`. It shows what react-router replace.

react-router changes browser url. But this doesn't make calls to server.
For communicate with server you can use jquery (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or superagent (https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know about this staff, I am more interesting about how this part [Server Side Rendering](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md) works inside